# How to call upon a function within a function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I don't know if this is possible I'm still new to python but I have a function within a function that I would like to call upon, Is it possible to call upon the add() or sub() function within the menu()? I've tried different ways to call upon it (every way I thought would make sense) but produced an error----name 'add' is not defined---

```
def menu():
    def add():
        print 6+6
    def sub():
        print 6-3
```

Comment: Can you show how you've tried to call them, and what the errors are (give the full traceback)? Also, why do you want to have the functions nested (it is usually unnecessary)?

Comment: menu(), menu(add()), menu().add(),menu([add()]) also just print add(). Im trying make a simple text based game and every time i learn something new I try to add it to my game. I understand (at least I think I do) that you can do that with classes but I havent learned that yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have defined your functions, `add` and `sub` are local names within the `menu` function. That means you can only access them directly while menu is running.

There are a few ways around this. You can have `menu` call them based on some conditions:

```
def menu(choice):
    def add():
        print 6+6
    def sub():
        print 6-3

    if choice == 'add':
        add() # call add here
    elif choice == 'sub':
        sub() # call sub here
```

Alternatively, you can have `menu` return one or more of the functions, which you can then give a new name in your calling code and then call later:

```
def menu(choice):
    def add():
        print 6+6
    def sub():
        print 6-3

    if choice == 'add':
        return add # returning the function, not calling it
    elif choice == 'sub':
        return sub # same here

func = menu('add')
func() # calls the add function defined in menu
```

However, none of these cases really show a good reason to define your `add` and `sub` functions within menu. It's often better to define them at the top-level of your code, even if you're going to call or return them from some other function (at a minimum, it will make testing them easier).

Answer (score 4):

Within the `menu()` function you call them directly after their definition:

```
def menu():
    def add():
        print 6+6
    def sub():
        print 6-3
    add()
    sub()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> menu()
12
3
```

To access them globally you can return those functions from `menu()` and assign them to global variables.

```
>>> def menu():
        def add():
                print 6+6
        def sub():
                print 6-3
        return add, sub
...     
>>> add, sub = menu()
>>> add()
12
>>> sub()
3
```

Answer (score 1):

how did you call it, it works fine for me:

```
def menu():
    def add():
        print 6+6
    def sub():
        print 6-3
    add()

>>> menu()
12
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a lambda for your single-use functions:

```
>>> def menu():
...     add = lambda x, y: x + y
...     sub = lambda x, y: x - y
...     print add(6, 6)
...     print sub(6, 3)
... 
>>> menu()
12
3
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's questions and nothing is gained by using a lambda here.